# How to debug the silk browser on the Kindle Fire?

Tags: javascript, kindle-fire

I am experiencing some different javascript behavior when running my site on Kindle Fire than through Chrome. In order to debug this I need access to something like the Chrome Developer Tool or Firebug. Any suggestions?

Comment: FWIW, I now use Weinre when I need to do this. jsconsole is great, but weinre provides the same debug tool as the chrome developer toolbar. It's a bit complicated to setup but worth it: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the same boat here... was hoping adb logcat would help, but javascript console messages don't seem to appear there.  Perhaps there's something that needs to be set on the device to direct console logs to logcat?

edit:  found a decent solution: http://jsconsole.com -- allows you to set up a remote debug/logging console.  Pretty simple (console logging only, so you'll need to dump a lot of into into the logs)... but it works well.  Helped me track down the source of my issues, at least!

how-to: http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html

Comment: :O Where has jsconsole.com been all my life? So helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach and created a wrapper native app that pop up a dialog for JavaScript.

My wrapper code is rather large, so I took a snippet of the relavant parts. It actually works and will display ANY javascript error.

```
// registers the debugger to catch errors 
WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
engine.setWebChromeClient(new DebugClient(this));

// the class that manages the errors
private class DebugClient extends WebChromeClient {
        Activity activity;

        public DebugClient(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            if (consoleMessage.messageLevel() == MessageLevel.ERROR
                    || consoleMessage.messageLevel() == MessageLevel.WARNING) {
                String title="Javascript error on line "
                        + String.valueOf(consoleMessage.lineNumber())
                        + " of " + consoleMessage.sourceId();
                AlertBox alertBox=new AlertBox(activity, (ActionListener)null, title, consoleMessage.message(), "OK");
                alertBox.show();
                alertBoxes.add(alertBox);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

To compile this, you'll need to install the Android SDK on your computer, and probably a Java IDE (Eclipse?) with ADT. Then you just do: create new project, add a WebView component into your layout/main.xml, and paste the code. Compile and install on your Kindle Fire.